# Mongoose - Pushing into subarray of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose object:

```
{
    "_id" : "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191",
    "name" : "MyCompany",
    "description": "whatever"
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "568ad3db59b494d4284ac19f",
            "fields" : {
                "Name" : "Item1",
                "Internal ID" : "ID00042",
                "tags" : [ 
                    {
                        "Description" : "Tag1",
                        "Level" : 2
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Description" : "Tag2",
                        "Level" : 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        },         {
            "_id" : "568ad3db59b494d4284ac19f",
            "fields" : {
                "Name" : "Item2",
                "Internal ID" : "ID00043",
                "tags" : [ 
                    {
                        "Description" : "Tag1",
                        "Level" : 5
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Description" : "Tag5",
                        "Level" : 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {..}
    ]
}
```

I need to push the following tag:

```
var obj = {
      "Description" : "myDescription",
      "Level" : 3
};
```

Into the following item's tag array:

```
var internal_id = "ID00102";
```

My attempt is not working:

```
Company.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191", "items.fields['Internal ID]": internal_id },
    {
        "$push": {
            "tags": thetag
        }
    },
    function(err,doc) {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
        return res.status(200).send(doc);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to add the tag object to the `tags` field. The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify the correct element in the `items` array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
Company.update(
    { "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191", "items.fields.Internal ID": internal_id },
    {
        "$push": {
            "items.$.fields.tags": thetag
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Company.findOneAndUpdate(
{ "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191", "items.fields['Internal ID]": internal_id },
    {
        "$push": {
            "tags": thetag
        }
    },
    function(err,doc) {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
        return res.status(200).send(doc);
    }
);
```

In the example above:

```
{ "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191", "items.fields['Internal ID]": internal_id },
```

MISSING  '  at "items.fields['Internal ID]"

Having spaces in object names isn't good practice as in "items.fields.Internal ID", it doesn't always work and gives some awkward issues. using internalId instead just makes things less awkward.